# git checkout only those files which were commited during the concrete commit

Tags: git, content-management-system, git-commit, git-checkout

I have a branch detached from head in my repo where I add folder under the same name with different files in it. Every time when I want to commit something I manually delete the folder in my repository and add the new one with the same name but the different content in it, which I later commit and push. The problem is that when I checkout one of my past commits I see that folder and it contains content from the selected commit and the past commits, but I want to see content ONLY from that concrete commit. So, I want to ask is it possible to do so and how should I achieve that? Maybe I should delete the files from my repo using some kind of git command? (But if its true I want to make sure that the files from the last commits wont be lost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time before committing, you should also remove from the tracked files all the files in the directory that *git* keep trace of, performing a `git rm your_directory`.

If you don't do it, *git* will remember that you had other files into the previous commit and will just *add* the differences, without removing the files that are not present in the new commit.

So you need to tell *git* that you are removing the files, and just after add again the new files with `git add your_directory`, after the copy of the new directory.

This way *git* will:

- understand that it has to remove the old files/directory
- add the new files/directory

You just have to do the same thing you are doing manually on the *"filesystem level"*, and do it also at *"git level"*.

Make me know if that is what you wanted to do!
And if that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to see a commit without exposing its full history. I think the best way to do this is using an orphan branch.

You do -

```
git --orphan <new_branch>
```

This will switch you to a new branch which is clean and you can then checkout to your desired commit which will then be the parent commit without any history attached to it.

Comment: This way won't he get a new branch for every commit he desires? Or this way all the commits for the *OP's directory copy* will still be resident into the same branch?